# Multiplicar select por radiobutton

Tags: javascript

Temos um radio button com três valores diferentes e um select box com vários valores diferentes, como eu poderia fazer para multiplicar o radiobutton checado com o valor da select box e colocar o resultado em um campo?

Código do radiobutton:

```
 <input required="required" value="1" name="diarias" id="diaria1"  type="radio"><label
  for="diaria">Uma diaria</label>
<input required="required"  value="2" name="diarias" id="diaria2" type="radio"><label
  for="diaria">Duas diarias</label>
<input required="required"  value="3" name="diarias" id="diaria3" type="radio"><label
  for="diaria">Três diarias</label><br>
```

Código do select box:

```
<select name="cidade" id="cidade" onclick="calcularopcoes();">
            <option name="nenhum" value=""> Escolher </option>
            <option name="saopaulo" value="244.00"> São Paulo </option>
            <option name="fortaleza" value="412.80"> Fortaleza </option>
            <option name="Blumenau" value="412.80"> Blumenau </option>
            <option name="riopreto" value="400.90"> Rio Preto </option>
            </select>
```

E o Javascript que eu tentei fazer mas não funcionou.

```
  `<script type="text/javascript">
            function calcularopcoes(){if(document.getElementById("ajudacusto").value.length < 0){
                    alert('Por favor, deve se        escolher uma opção');
                    document.getElementById("ajudacusto").focus();
                    return false
                    }
                if(document.getElementByName("diarias").value.length < 0){
                    alert('Por favor, deve se escolher uma opção');
                    document.getElementByName("diarias").focus();
                    return false
                    }


                // vamos obter o elemento select
            var elem = document.getElementById("cidade");    
            var elem2 = document.getElementByName("diarias");
            var selecionou = elem.options[elem.options.selectedIndex]*1 * elem2.options[elem2.options.selectedIndex]*1;
            // passa opção selecionada para campo
            document.getElementById("ajudacusto").value = selecionou.value;
    }  
   </script>`
```

De que melhor maneira podemos fazer? Que ao usuário clicar na diaria e escolher a cidade ele faça o calculo de multiplicação automaticamente e deposite no campo?

Comment: Falta algum HTML. Se puder junte também. QUer fazer isto com javascript puro ou é OK com uma biblioteca?

Comment: Tudo isso em um formulário, como assim falta algum html? Pode ser com biblioteca sim.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Mudar propriedades de radio button a partir de escolha em select](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12350/mudar-propriedades-de-radio-button-a-partir-de-escolha-em-select)

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que a outra questão deveria ser duplicada dessa, e não o contrário, pois: 1) Essa questão aqui foi criada antes; 2) Essa questão aqui tem uma resposta aceita, a outra não tem. PS: Eu nem li o conteúdo das duas, só fiz uma observarão caso sejam mesmo duplicadas.

Comment: Acho que não é duplicata pois aqui o objetivo é apenas multiplicar enquanto na outra pergunta o objetivo é mudar os valores dos atributos de acordo com a seleção também.

Comment: Ok, só achei que eram parecidas, por isso fiz a sugestão. Um boa discussão para o meta. Quando se encontra um novo problema no mesmo código, editar ou criar novo tópico?

Comment: Cuidado com as [perguntas camaleão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1115/3117).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinicius, aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[name=diarias], select");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('click', calcularopcoes);
    }
}

function calcularopcoes() {
    var diarias = document.querySelectorAll("[name=diarias]"); // pegar em todas as checkbox
    var escolhida = false; // criar uma flag
    for (var i = 0; i < diarias.length; i++) { // percorre-las uma a uma
        if (diarias[i].checked) escolhida = diarias[i]; // se alguma estiver escolhida a flag passa a "true"
    }
    if (!escolhida) { // se nenhuma estiver escolhida lançar o alert
        alert('Por favor, deve se escolher uma opção');
        document.querySelector("[name=diarias]").focus();
        return false
    }


    // vamos obter o elemento select
    var elem = document.getElementById("cidade");
    var selecionou = elem.options[elem.options.selectedIndex].value;
    // passa opção selecionada para campo
    var valorFinal = selecionou * escolhida.value; // escolhida está em cache, é só ir buscar o valor (.value)
    document.getElementById("ajudacusto").value = valorFinal ;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGpDT/)

Outro exemplo, com jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/LGpDT/3/
Outro exemplo, com MooTools: http://jsfiddle.net/LGpDT/4/

Na primeira parte junto a cada checkbox e select um event listener para correr a sua função a cada click ( assim pode tirar o `onclick` do seu HTML)

Comment: Bacana, o código ficou bem diferente do que eu pensava, juro que ainda não consigo me acostumar com javascript... Em todo caso, vou testar aqui já te respondo. Obrigado :)
Esse javascript vai por ultimo ou vai na tag <head>?

Comment: @Vinicius, pode ir na tag head, se for no fim pode tirar o window.onload e deixar só o que está dentro

Comment: Muito interessante esse `querySelectorAll`! Não costumo trabalhar com JavaScript puro, então não estou por dentro das facilidades que a API oferece.

Comment: Funcionou totalmente, ainda melhorando adicionei o toFixed() da resposta do @mgibsonbr para mostrar somente 2 casas depois da virgula. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns problemas no seu código:

1. `document.getElementByName` não existe. Como seu próprio código demonstra, podem existir mais de um elemento com o mesmo nome. Substitua o teste por `getElementsByName` (elements, no plural):

   ```
   var diarias = document.getElementsByName("diarias");
   for ( var i = 0 ; i < diarias.length ; i++ ) { ... }
   ```
2. Para ver se um radio button está selecionado, use a propriedade `checked`:

   ```
   var selecionado = null;
   var diarias = document.getElementsByName("diarias");
   for ( var i = 0 ; i < diarias.length ; i++ )
       if ( diarias[i].checked )
           selecionado = diarias[i];
   if(!selecionado){
       alert('Por favor, deve se escolher uma opção');
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Você está tentando multiplicar **elementos** em vez de multiplicar seus valores:

   ```
   var selecionou = elem.options[elem.options.selectedIndex]*1 * elem2.options[elem2.options.selectedIndex]*1;
   ```

   Use os valores em vez disso (usando a varíável `selecionado` criada anteriormente):

   ```
    var elem2 = selecionado;
   var selecionou = elem.options[elem.options.selectedIndex].value * elem2.value;
   // passa opção selecionada para campo
   document.getElementById("ajudacusto").value = selecionou;
   ```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xPJfm/).

P.S. Você está usando ponto flutuante para representar dinheiro? Isso não é uma boa ideia, veja o que acontece ao escolher "três diárias em Rio Preto". Esses erros de arredondamento podem ser "ocultados" usando a função `toFixed` no valor (faz com que ele se imprima com um número fixo de casas decimais), mas é preciso também ter cuidado com o restante do código.

```
document.getElementById("ajudacusto").value = selecionou.toFixed(2);
```

[Exemplo atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/xPJfm/1/).

Comment: Boa resposta :) `+1`

Comment: Acabei de perceber que não temos uma "pergunta canônica" sobre a forma de representar dinheiro em JavaScript... [Abri uma nova pergunta quanto a isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/215)

Comment: Interessante esse toFixed pois além de limitar a duas casas decimais (como é o dinheiro) fica esteticamente melhor pois se o resultado for 100 por exemplo ao invés de aparecer 100 ele mostra 100,00. O que me faz pensar em outra coisa, tenho um campo tipo float o usuário pode digitar o dinheiro tanto com ponto (que o banco de dados aceita) tanto com virgula (que o banco de dados não aceita e corta os centavos), tem alguma função em PHP ou JS pra tratar essa informação corretamente? Mas isso eu posso depois pesquisar/perguntar, mesmo assim, obrigado pois uma resposta completou a outra.

Comment: @Vinicius, pode lavar o dinheiro assim: `function lavarDinheiro(valor){ return ('' + valor).replace(/,/g, '.')}` hehe, isto é substituir virgular por pontos :) __mgibsonr__: boa pergunta nova que você lançou :)