# Mudar propriedades de radio button a partir de escolha em select

Tags: javascript, html, json

Prezado(s) Me vejo na seguinte situação na qual não imagino solução:

Temos um campo de seleção em html contendo alguns estados Brasileiros e o Distrito federal, ao escolher uma opção, isso me levaria a abrir mais um tipo de escolha um radio button, entre Capital e Interior sendo cada capital e a opção de interior com seus respectivos valores, aonde eu pegaria esse valor da determinada capital ou do interior e levaria a fazer uma conta multiplicando um valor de um outro radio button equivalente as diárias pra ai então mostrar esse valor em um campo texto.

`Exemplo
Numero de diárias: ()Uma diária (x)Duas diárias ()Três diárias
Selecione o estado: Select SP\/
//Apareceria outro radio button: 
(x)São Paulo () Interior`

No caso de São Paulo o valor seria R$200.00 vezes a diária
então o textfield com a ajuda do javascript seria:
Valor = 400,00

```
            <select name="estado" id="estado" >
            <option name="nenhum" value=""> Escolher </option>
            <option name="DF" value="DF"> Distrito Federal </option>
            <option name="SP" value="SP"> São Paulo </option>
            <option name="outros" value="Outros"> Outros Estados 
</option>
```

//Abre múltipla escolha de duas opções se o usuário escolheu o Distrito Federal,  então

```
<input required="required" value="Brasília" name="capital" type="radio">  
<label for="capital">Brasília</label> <input required="required"  value="Interior" name="capital" type="radio"><label         for="capital">Interior</label>
```

//Note que dependendo do campo select o `valor` e o `label` do radio button mudaria. 
//Logo mais a diária para Brasília tem valor de 250.30 e o interior é fixo para todos os estados 160.00. 
 
Nesse ponto eu precisaria fazer a conta imagino eu com `IFs` para cada capital e multiplicar com o valor do elemento diarias do radio button lá em cima.

Essa foi a maneira como eu pensei. Teria como eu fazer isso ou de outra forma na qual eu chegasse ao mesmo resultado? Que é ter o nome da capital para poder gravar no banco de dados, e o valor da capital para fazer a conta com as diárias.
Como eu poderia fazer isso em Json ou Javascript?

Comment: Eu não percebi se queres ter todos os estados e respetivos preços na base de dados? Queres usar o `javascript` para inserir na base de dados?

Comment: Não, quero ter todos os nomes de Estados e nomes de Capitais, quero usar o javascript para trocar a variável capital para a capital de acordo com o estado. Ex: SP -> São Paulo, RJ -> Rio de Janeiro, AC -> Rio Branco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha vê se é isto que queres?

[EDIT]
Tens aqui um update com o problema todo:
http://jsfiddle.net/q3N95/17/
Verifica se é isso que querias, qualquer coisa é só perguntar.

```
<input id="d1" required="required" value="1" name="diaria" type="radio">  
<label id="diaria" for="diaria">Uma diária</label> 

<input id="d2" required="required" value="2" name="diaria" type="radio">  
<label id="diaria" for="diaria">Duas diárias</label> 

<input id="d3" required="required" value="3" name="diaria" type="radio">  
<label id="diaria" for="diaria">Três diária</label> 
<br>

<select name="estado" id="estado" onChange="trocaEstado();">
   <option id="nenhum"  value="0"  > Escolher         </option>
   <option id="DF"      value="250"> Distrito Federal </option>
   <option id="SP"      value="200"> São Paulo        </option>
   <option id="outros"  value="300"> Outros Estados   </option>
</select>
<br>

<input id="input_capital" required="required" value="0" name="capital" type="radio" >  
<label id="capital" for="capital">Escolher</label> 
<input id="input_interior" required="required"  value="160" name="capital" type="radio">
<label id="interiror" for="capital">Interior</label>
<br>
<br>

<label for="resultado">Resultado</label> 
<input readonly="readonly" id="resultado" value="Zero"></input>
<br>
<!--input para o estado -->
<label for="estado_s">Estado</label> 
<input readonly="readonly" id="estado_s" value="nenhum"></input>    

<script>

function trocaEstado()
{
    var e        = document.getElementById("estado");
    var strcap   = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var strvalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //vai buscar o id da option
    var estado_s = e.options[e.selectedIndex].id;


    document.getElementById('input_capital').value=strvalue;
    document.getElementById('input_capital').checked=false;
    document.getElementById('capital').innerHTML=strcap;

    //mete o id da option no input estado_s
    document.getElementById('estado_s').value=estado_s;

}

 $(document).ready(function() {
    var capital=null;
    var diaria=null;
    $('input:radio[name=capital]').change(function() {
       capital = this.value;
       if(diaria)
           document.getElementById('resultado').value=(capital*diaria);
    });
    $('input:radio[name=diaria]').change(function() {
       diaria = this.value;
       if(capital)
           document.getElementById('resultado').value=(capital*diaria);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Legal...Não usou if nenhum.
É quase isso, mas com uma dúvida eu preciso guardar no banco de dados quando eu submeter essas informações, por exemplo o estado eu teria que guardar o nome do estado `name= "SP"` e não seu valor, o seu valor eu posso fazer direto multiplicando o valor pela diária como esta no seu exemplo e só guardar o valor do campo que a conta foi. O mesmo vale para capital e interior, exceto que o valor de interior é igual para todos os estados, o que muda mesmo é o valor da capital.

Comment: Por isso na página de submissão eu não posso fazer
`if($_POST['estado']==200.00)
$estado = "São Paulo";` pois pode haver outra capital com o mesmo valor de 200.00

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Onde é que tu vais buscar os valores de cada estado?

Comment: Pois é, os valores de cada estado separadamente eu não salvo eu só uso para fazer a conta com as diárias e guardar o resultado no campo como esta o seu exemplo. `id = "resultado"` No entanto eu precisaria guardar uma string do nome do estado, poderia ser qualquer informação que esta em destaque:
<option `name="SP"` value="200"> São Paulo </option>
//guardar o SP ou
<option name="SP" value="200"> `São Paulo` </option>
// o "Rótulo" São Paulo
Isso com cada estado.

Se não tiver como, e ou o que você me sugere?
Obrigado.

Comment: Vê agora com as alterações que fiz. Adicionei um input para o estado depois já tens como ir buscar.

Comment: Isso aí, vou testar aqui já te falo. :)

Comment: Cuidado com o `readonly` que pode dar problemas ao passar como `POST`, experimenta antes `disabled`

Comment: Tirei o `reandonly` e coloquei `disabled`, coloquei também como o resultado se refere a dinheiro, um `toFixed()` no final do calculo do resultado. Transformei o campo que recebe a id do estado em `hidden` pra não repetir informação uma vez que já foi declarado lá no select box em cima. Nota - se a minha inconsistência que eu não tinha pensado antes, nem sempre a capital tem o mesmo nome do estado, então só escrevi do lado < de opção capital/interior `Capital de` pra não me complicar mais ainda.
http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-09-04-2014-164149.php
Obrigado @Jorge B. :)